# Generate nonoverlapping random circles

Tags: graphics, random

I want to distribute n circles unformly in an area(e.g. free plannar space). The circles could touch each other but cannot overlap.

```
n = 5;
r = 0.2;
Table[pt[i] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], {i, 1, n}];
Graphics[{Table[Circle[pt[i], r], {i, n}]}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

My method is to generate the random points firstly, and then calculate the smallest distance between all point pairs. If the smallest distance is larger than 2r, the points are kept. However, the problem with this method is that the larger the radius, the more trials have to be taken.
   [image]

Comment: Previously: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11940/484

Comment: Somewhat related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22896

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/efficient-way-to-generate-random-points-with-a-predefined-lower-bound-on-their-p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a bunch of `Region` functions that just showed up in 10.  This uses `RegionDistance[]` to make a function that computes the shortest distance from a point to a region.  The generated function runs faster than just checking all the circles.  Though the creation of the function in the first place has to look at all the circles.  So this still runs in $\mathrm O(n^2)$ time, but at least the inner `While` should be faster when there are already a lot of circles and not a lot of places to put a new one.

```
distinct[n_,r_]:=Module[{d,f,p},
  d={Circle[RandomReal[{-1,1},2],r]};
  Do[
    f=RegionDistance[RegionUnion@@d];
    While[p=RandomReal[{-1,1},2];f[p]<r];
    d=Append[d,Circle[p,r]],
    {n-1}];
  d
]
```

Example:

```
distinct[75, 0.1] // Graphics
```

[image: 75 non-overlapping circles]

The following runs quite a bit faster, generating a `Nearest` function for a large set of circles, and using that one function to eliminate many overlaps in a single pass.

```
sweep[pts_,r_]:=Module[{p,f,c},
  p=pts;
  While[
    f=Nearest[p->Automatic];
    c=f[p,{2,r}];
    Last[Dimensions[c]]!=1,
    p=Pick[p,First[#]<=Last[#]&/@c];
  ];
  p
]

distinct2[n_,r_]:=Module[{p},
  p={};
  While[
    p=Join[p,RandomReal[{-1,1},{n,2}]];
    p=sweep[p,2r];
    Length[p]<n
  ];
  Circle[#,r]&/@Take[p,n]
]
```

Measuring the performance (your mileage may vary):

```
Timing[distinct[75,0.1];]
```

> ```
> {3.021209,Null}
> ```

```
Timing[distinct2[75,0.1];]
```

> ```
> {0.077105,Null}
> ```

A problem with both of these algorithms is that there is no assurance that they will halt.  You can ask for too many circles, and end up with the `While` loops trying to add circles forever when there is no place to put even one.  If this is supposed to be part of some larger automated process, then you need to add a check for no progress after so many tries in order to give up.  E.g.:

```
distinct3[n_,r_,maxiter_]:=Module[{p,m,k},
  p={};
  m=0;
  k=maxiter;
  While[
    p=Join[p,RandomReal[{-1,1},{n,2}]];
    p=sweep[p,2r];
    k=If[Length[p]>m,maxiter,k-1];
    m=Length[p];
    m<n&&k>0
  ];
  Circle[#,r]&/@If[Length[p]>n,Take[p,n],p]
]
```

Then:

```
distinct3[100,0.1,1000]//Length
```

> ```
> 80
> ```

```
distinct3[100,0.1,1000]//Length
```

> ```
> 78
> ```

As pointed out by Ernst Stelzer, this works in 3D just as well with two small changes:

```
distinct3D[n_,r_,maxiter_]:=Module[{p,m,k},
  p={};
  m=0;
  k=maxiter;
  While[
    p=Join[p,RandomReal[{-1,1},{n,3}]];
    p=sweep[p,2r];
    k=If[Length[p]>m,maxiter,k-1];
    m=Length[p];
    m<n&&k>0
  ];
  Sphere[#,r]&/@If[Length[p]>n,Take[p,n],p]
]
```

Then:

```
distinct3D[150, 0.2, 100]//Graphics3D
```

[image: 118 spheres of radius 0.2 packed into 2x2x2 box]

That is 118 spheres.

I'd show you one in four dimensions, except that there's no `HyperSphere[]` or `Graphics4D[]`.  Perhaps someone could work on those.

And now for something completely different.  @novice did not ask that the circles be placed randomly, rather that the circles be distributed "uniformly".  You can get more circles in if they are not placed randomly.  This hexagonally packs in as many circles as possible of radius *r*, and then removes any excess circles randomly:

```
distinctx[n_,r_]:=Module[{x,c},
  x={
    2Floor[1/(2r)+1/2]-1,
    2Floor[1/(2r)],
    Sqrt[3](2Floor[1/(2Sqrt[3]r)+1/2]-1),
    2Sqrt[3]Floor[1/(2Sqrt[3]r)]}//
    Min[1/Select[#,#>0&]]&;
  c=Join[
    Table[Circle[x{2 i+1,Sqrt[3]j},r],
      {i,-Floor[1/(2x)+1/2],Floor[1/(2x)-1/2]},
      {j,-1-2Floor[1/(2Sqrt[3]x)-1/2],1+2Floor[1/(2Sqrt[3]x)-1/2],2}]
      //Flatten,
    Table[Circle[x{2 i,Sqrt[3]j},r],
      {i,-Floor[1/(2x)],Floor[1/(2x)]},
      {j,-2Floor[1/(2Sqrt[3]x)],2Floor[1/(2Sqrt[3]x)],2}]
      //Flatten];
  If[Length[c]>n,RandomSample[c,n],c]
]
```

For example:

```
distinctx[10,0.15]//
Graphics[{Blue,Line[{{-1,-1},{-1,1},{1,1},{1,-1},{-1,-1}}],Black,#}]&
```

[image: random sample of hex arrangement]

```
distinctx[40,0.15]//
Graphics[{Blue,Line[{{-1,-1},{-1,1},{1,1},{1,-1},{-1,-1}}],Black,#}]&
```

[image: just a few missing]

You're very unlikely to be able to get 40 circles of radius 0.15 stuffed in there randomly.

Comment: '@Mark Adler, thanks. Your method is faster than mine(especially when n is large), and the generated circles are close to uniform distribution.

Comment: @MarkAdler very nice. I noticed that having 'RandomReal' produce three numbers '{n,3}' and using 'Sphere' instead of 'Circle' produces perfect collections of spheres in 3D.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to approach this: generate a collection of random circles and then throw out all those that are too close to another. For example, generate 20 centers with a box of size {-5,5} and with radius 1. Then throw out those that overlap others.

```
n = 20; rad = 1; centers = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {n, 2}];
allCircles = Table[near = Nearest[centers, centers[[i]], 2]; test = First@Rest@near;
   If[Norm[First@near - test] < 2 rad, centers[[i]] = {-100, 100}, centers[[i]]], {i, 1, n}];
circles = Select[allCircles, # != {-100, 100} &];
Graphics[Table[Circle[circles[[i]], rad], {i, 1, Length[circles]}]]
```

[image]

Or, with slightly different parameters

[image]

Comment: '@bill s, Thanks. A minor flaw is that the number of circles cann't be guaranted(suppose I want n circles, and n is large). I propose to use this method `how-to-generate-random-points-in-a-region` when the distribution is dense.