# How to deal with these source vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

This is uncompleted answer for [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22896/efficiently-filling-area-with-disks-located-at-certain-points) based on `NearestNeighborGraph`.I'm lost in how to deal with that source vertices(whose vertex in-degree is 0.) in `g`,but it has better efficiency than [accepted answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22898/21532) currently.Maybe somebody can finish it,so I post it still:

```
SeedRandom[8]
p = RandomReal[10, {400, 2}];
g = NearestNeighborGraph[p, 1, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

```
c = Catenate[
   Thread[Rule[List @@ #, EuclideanDistance @@ #/2]] & /@ 
    First /@ FindCycle[g, {2}, All]];
circle = Catenate[
   FixedPointList[
    Function[c, 
     Rule[#, EuclideanDistance[#, 
          t = Last[VertexOutComponent[g, #, 1]]] - (t /. c)] & /@ 
      Complement[VertexInComponent[g, First /@ c, 1], First /@ c]], 
    c]];
Graphics[{Circle @@@ circle}]
```

[image]

As you can see,there are some overlap circles.They are all source vertices.If I don't draw it,it will not be overlap anymore:

```
Graphics[{Circle @@@ 
   Select[circle, VertexInDegree[g, First[#]] != 0 &]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you be clearer about what the question is that you need help with?

Comment: @bills I want to by this thinking to solve that [link question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22896/efficiently-filling-area-with-disks-located-at-certain-points) to avoid to use violence method like as the current [accepted answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22898/21532).